# Prove a set equidecomposable with a paradoxical set is paradoxical

Tags: group-theory, paradoxes

In Stan Wagon's book *The Banach-Tarski Paradox*, Proposition 3.4 is written as: "Suppose $G$ acts on $X$ and $E$, $E'$ are $G$-decomposable subsets of $X$. If $E$ is $G$-paradoxical, so is $E'$. I have not written the proof itself since it is omitted from Google Books, but what is a straightforward way to understand the intuition behind this relation? If the sets were isomorphic it would be fairly obvious, but I am missing the nuance of how a paradoxical decomposition 'lays in' with the relation under equidecomposability.

Comment: I suppose that $G$-decomposable means that the action of $G$ is free?

Comment: For the question in the title: Cut $E'$ into finitely many peaces and reassemble them into $E$, cut $E$ into finitely many pieces and rearrange them into two copies of $E$, cut each copy into finitely many pieces and rearrange into two copies of $E'$. Overall, you have cut $E'$ into finitely many pieces and rearranged these into two copies of $E'$

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks!